# PHP Inheritance - Access methods between child classes

Tags: php, inheritance, methods

Im working with PHP inheritance, I have a parent class named "base" and two more child classes named "A" and "B".

The thing is that im declaring a method in my "A" class and I need to access to that method from the "B" class.

I know how to access to them from the parent class, but I dont know if it is possible to access to the methods between the child classes.

Comment: This is impossible. Child classes know __nothing__ about each other.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve that requires you to access a method of A from B? Maybe there is a better solution that avoids this issue altogether.

Comment: Why don't you just declare that method on the parent "base" class? So both child classes have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

Call another child class of the parent is impossible. You can just make a new instance of A class inside B class, and then call to methods through it.

Answer (score 0):

If your `declaring a method in my "A" class and I need to access to that method from the "B" class`, then you should not be writing that `method` in `A` class.

Abstract it out into its own scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new instance of that class where the method is called inside another method.